# want to avoid hiding previous li elements with CSS box-shadow

Tags: html, css

I have a list where each element has a box shadow behind it to make it stand out against some background:

```css
html {
  background: black;
}

span {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 0 white, -2px 0 0 white, 2px 10px 0 white, 2px 20px 0 white, 2px 30px 0 white, 2px 40px 0 white, 2px 50px 0 white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>California</span></li>
  <li><span>Idaho</span></li>
  <li><span>Maine</span></li>
  <li><span>Oregon</span></li>
</ul>
```

However, if I try to make the box shadow project *up* instead of *down*, it covers the previous element's text:

```css
html {
  background: black;
}

span {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 0 white, -2px 0 0 white, 2px -10px 0 white, 2px -20px 0 white, 2px -30px 0 white, 2px -40px 0 white, 2px -50px 0 white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>California</span></li>
  <li><span>Idaho</span></li>
  <li><span>Maine</span></li>
  <li><span>Oregon</span></li>
</ul>
```

Is there any way to avoid this, and have the box shadow always behind the text? Thanks.

Comment: This is because of the order in which the elements are displayed. The last `li` element is in front of every other element and therefore it covers the elements behind, and so on. What you could do is to play maybe with the `z-index` of each `li` element, although it is not the most practical solution.

Comment: This has been bugging me: do you only need the top one to have the long drop-shadow going to the top of the page? Because if so, there's a *really* easy, obvious solution without any of the drawbacks of the two I suggested below!

Comment: Nope, all of them actually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every solution I can think of has some unfortunate compromise.

The boring, not-very-extensible, answer is to use a descending `z-index`. You can automate this with a preprocessor like SASS (if you know the maximum number of items in advance) or JavaScript; let me know if you want to do either.

```css
html {
  background: black;
}

span {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 0 white, -2px 0 0 white, 2px -10px 0 white, 2px -20px 0 white, 2px -30px 0 white, 2px -40px 0 white, 2px -50px 0 white;
}

li {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

li:nth-child(2) {
  z-index: 3;
}

li:nth-child(3) {
  z-index: 2;
}

li:nth-child(4) {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>California</span></li>
  <li><span>Idaho</span></li>
  <li><span>Maine</span></li>
  <li><span>Oregon</span></li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, if you're willing to invert the order of your list items in your markup (grim, but possibly acceptable), you can use flexbox—specifically the `flex-direction` property—to reverse the order in which elements are oriented along the main axis.

```css
html {
  background: black;
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

span {
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 0 white, -2px 0 0 white, 2px -10px 0 white, 2px -20px 0 white, 2px -30px 0 white, 2px -40px 0 white, 2px -50px 0 white;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Oregon</span></li>
  <li><span>Maine</span></li>
  <li><span>Idaho</span></li>
  <li><span>California</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not the best solution, not even by far but it should get you going

```css
html {
  background: black;
}

span.h {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 0;
  background: white;
  box-shadow: 2px 0 0 white, -2px 0 0 white, 2px -10px 0 white;
}

span.i {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span class='h'>California</span><span class='i'>California</span></li>
  <li><span class='h'>Oregon</span><span class='i'>Oregon</span></li>
  <li><span class='h'>Washington</span><span class='i'>Washington</span></li>
  <li><span class='h'>Idaho</span><span class='i'>Idaho</span></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can just add a css...**

```
ul li{margin:10px 0;}
```

Comment: I can't seem to do this without affecting the spacing of the items; I would like them to be tight as in the supplied snippet.